# scanf - strange behavior: two consecutive calls results in one different string and one correct string

Tags: c, string, scanf

I encountered this behavior while trying to solve [this HackerRank problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/two-strings). This site uses `scanf` to pass well-formatted data to the user's code. So far, so good.

There are `p` pairs of strings, each string on a separate line. For each pair, I only need to print `YES` or `NO` once, depending on whether or not those two strings have a common substring. Straightforward enough, for sure. But I'm failing test cases for no apparent reason.

So, after debugging with `printf`, it turns out that, when calling `scanf` twice, for some reason the first string becomes a shorter version with the second string appended to it - an overlap. The second string appears normally on the next line.

The code in question (in debug-mode, if you so will):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int p;
    scanf("%d", &p);

    char *s1 = malloc(sizeof(s1));
    char *s2 = malloc(sizeof(s2));
    int len1, len2;
    char *answers[] = { "NO", "YES"};
    int answers_i;
    for(int i = 0; i < p; ++i) {
        scanf("%s", s1);
        scanf("%s", s2);
        printf("%s\n%s\n", s1, s2);
        len1 = strlen(s1);
        len2 = strlen(s2);
        answers_i = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < len1 && answers_i == 0; ++j) {
            for(int k = 0; k < len2; ++k) {
                if(s1[j] == s2[k]) {
                    // printf("s1[%d]=%c s2[%d]=%c\n", j, s1[j], k, s2[k]);
                    answers_i = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        // printf("%s\n", answers[answers_i]);
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

Input of one of the failed test cases:

```
10
dapkqnowwvdrknfvcmanjuroumppajrzklucroxvpfmcsclqa
ivtnjtgiogmwhqybjaxlktqbwsdhqrwovoavetymkpcco
hrtybirxncuiailznohfawjwipdtupnxnisbwcplozwrzt
ngdmqotxkpnuhmpfmajthzdtnztrqyugendiublcwp
rmpwlddwttapjzhdldjmuhmgruufltzszprzdcziigc
bbvvkeqkqekqqennyxqxkxnyxnyqnnybnbvnyqqe
annbjookwtqkoivcgbqckqtvgvktobctktgkkjiac
zsspfhmzpurrrlurdsdlrfldzyldfhudfedrszdpmsudh
yuuuydwovzawzamvydaaadkakukpynwfmpnmuaazokxkmjxawo
rqiqbhgscsetgihrrrgsqrlqgcbcbrettlehbeistbiqbisie
ibvmfltfdvlmentbfdemebbnvllfneeefnaamtblt
gukzzrqruyxsrqhyuggkrjujkwjhqhqsrqgkrkqxpszrzk
nakqzfroqouhgunxqvqbxwtibfodsvoilqrpvhtgzoholxd
bqluorjgkkrvmiptnxegxwlhrstiiafbfoxodzyguhdwi
oyvgelovlyevhhedoeolyhdevcvhgceydcdehgvoc
wsqswjnjpiarszzzxpmptrquwbnbzqiqqtzqnbajnpsjfaxr
hvkmgwawagozzabgmdmdvbbaxadawmbazvxohxzv
sfiltrslqepytjpfffqlrpejiueftrnisnnppnlpuficrjys
nvsovybaljmzenkfgayfoxzcjantbdidxflbkhbixgzk
qdphnbrjmznztnphhutkdbwjzmjwugtxggxchzcidngplj
```

Output

```
dapkqnowwvdrknfvcmanjuroumppajrzivtnjtgiogmwhqybjaxlktqbwsdhqrwovoavetymkpcco
ivtnjtgiogmwhqybjaxlktqbwsdhqrwovoavetymkpcco
hrtybirxncuiailznohfawjwipdtupnxngdmqotxkpnuhmpfmajthzdtnztrqyugendiublcwp
ngdmqotxkpnuhmpfmajthzdtnztrqyugendiublcwp
rmpwlddwttapjzhdldjmuhmgruufltzsbbvvkeqkqekqqennyxqxkxnyxnyqnnybnbvnyqqe
bbvvkeqkqekqqennyxqxkxnyxnyqnnybnbvnyqqe
annbjookwtqkoivcgbqckqtvgvktobctzsspfhmzpurrrlurdsdlrfldzyldfhudfedrszdpmsudh
zsspfhmzpurrrlurdsdlrfldzyldfhudfedrszdpmsudh
yuuuydwovzawzamvydaaadkakukpynwfrqiqbhgscsetgihrrrgsqrlqgcbcbrettlehbeistbiqbisie
rqiqbhgscsetgihrrrgsqrlqgcbcbrettlehbeistbiqbisie
ibvmfltfdvlmentbfdemebbnvllfneeegukzzrqruyxsrqhyuggkrjujkwjhqhqsrqgkrkqxpszrzk
gukzzrqruyxsrqhyuggkrjujkwjhqhqsrqgkrkqxpszrzk
nakqzfroqouhgunxqvqbxwtibfodsvoibqluorjgkkrvmiptnxegxwlhrstiiafbfoxodzyguhdwi
bqluorjgkkrvmiptnxegxwlhrstiiafbfoxodzyguhdwi
oyvgelovlyevhhedoeolyhdevcvhgceywsqswjnjpiarszzzxpmptrquwbnbzqiqqtzqnbajnpsjfaxr
wsqswjnjpiarszzzxpmptrquwbnbzqiqqtzqnbajnpsjfaxr
hvkmgwawagozzabgmdmdvbbaxadawmbasfiltrslqepytjpfffqlrpejiueftrnisnnppnlpuficrjys
sfiltrslqepytjpfffqlrpejiueftrnisnnppnlpuficrjys
nvsovybaljmzenkfgayfoxzcjantbdidqdphnbrjmznztnphhutkdbwjzmjwugtxggxchzcidngplj
qdphnbrjmznztnphhutkdbwjzmjwugtxggxchzcidngplj
```

The output should equal the input, but this is obviously not the case. The first string is being capped at 32 characters and the entire second string is appended to it. But the second string itself is unchanged. What exactly is happening between these two `scanf` calls?

I used `gets` (oops, deprecated) and `getchar`, but the problem persists. `fgets` is useless, since I don't know the size of the strings beforehand. I don't know any other standard alternatives.

NOTE: If anyone wants to try out this code on HackerRank, make sure to check the box for `Test against custom input`, copy&paste the input above, then click the `Run` button.

Comment: `char *s1 = malloc(sizeof(s1));` allocates 4 or 8 bytes, which is not enough.

Comment: The constraints says that the size of the inputs can be up to 100000 bytes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code has undefined behavior. The problem in your code is with the allocation of memory to `s1` and `s2`. You allocate `sizeof(s1)` bytes, which is the size of a pointer. Once you read more data than the size of a pointer, you write past the allocated buffer, causing undefined behavior.

Problem constraints call for |a|, |b| < 10<sup>5</sup>, so the allocation should be as follows:

```
char *s1 = malloc(100000 + 1);
char *s2 = malloc(100000 + 1);
```

Note an extra byte allocated for null terminator.

You need to call `free(s1)` and `free(s2)` at the end of your function.

Comment: In the previous problems scanf did fine with just a pointer allocated. Was this in fact undefined behavior and gcc just happened to decide that it should automatically allocate additional memory?

Comment: @MiroslavCetojevic Unless all strings had length of under 3 or 7 characters, depending on your platform, this was indeed undefined behavior. `malloc` allocates a little more than you ask for when you pass a small number, so the code could run fine even with UB (the code was still incorrect). You can test your code for UB with [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).

Comment: Yeah, most strings were longer than 7 characters. Learned something new.